# save selector in cookie and get that cookie back

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, cookies

I want to ask the user in my webapp with a drop-down menu which school website they want to open, then save that in a cookie and automatically open that website next time they open the webapp. I'm not good at JS so please explain.

Thank's in advance.

```
<head>
<script>
 <!-- Cookie script -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select id="class">
          <option value="Choose">Choose</option>
          <option value="flah">School#1</option> <!-- Should redirect to site #1 -->
          <option value="june">School#2</option> <!-- Should redirect to site #2 -->
        </select>
        <button type="submit">V&auml;lj</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Update:

<

```
form>
        <select id="class">
          <option value="Choose">Choose</option>
          <option value="flah">School#1</option> <!-- Should redirect to site #1 -->
          <option value="june">School#2</option> <!-- Should redirect to site #2 -->
        </select>
        <button type="submit" onclick="setCookie()">V&auml;lj</button>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">    
    function setCookie(cookiename, cookievalue, cookieexdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (cookieexdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cookiename+ "=" + cookievalue+ "; " + expires;
    }

    function getCookie(cookiename) {
        var name = cookiename+ "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }

    function checkCookie() {
        var school = getCookie("SelectedSchool");
        if (school!= "") {
            //redirect to user to link
            alert("Welcome to the " + school);
        } else {
            user = prompt("Please choose your name:", "");
            if (school != "" && school != null) {
                setCookie("SelectedSchool", school, 365);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a cookie use:

```
document.cookie="key=value";
```

To get the value of the select use (example in jquery):

```
var val = $("#class").val();
```

Save that in the cookie.
Now next time the user logs in read the cookie using:

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

and redirect him with:

```
location.href = "link";
```

good luck

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry but this is the first time I'm doing it, is it just copy paste or do I need to add anything?

Comment: Change the key to the name of how you want to call the cookie. Change the value to the value you get. and of course change the link to the page you want to go to. for more info check this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for my ignorance of JS, but can you please explain every step?

Comment: Let's do it...
first add a listener and a function that with each change will get the value of the select and save it in a cookie:
$(document).on("change", "#class", function(){
var value = $(this).val();

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this, These are the JavaScript function which you can use to save, get or check cookie

```
<head>
<script>
 <!-- Cookie script -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select id="class">
          <option value="Choose">Choose</option>
          <option value="flah">School#1</option> <!-- Should redirect to site #1 -->
          <option value="june">School#2</option> <!-- Should redirect to site #2 -->
        </select>
        <button type="submit">V&auml;lj</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function setCookie(cookiename, cookievalue, cookieexdays) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (cookieexdays*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = cookiename+ "=" + cookievalue+ "; " + expires;
        }

        function getCookie(cookiename) {
            var name = cookiename+ "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
            return "";
        }

        function checkCookie() {
            var school = getCookie("SelectedSchool");
            if (school!= "") {
                //redirect to user to link
                alert("Welcome to the " + school);
            } else {
                user = prompt("Please choose your name:", "");
                if (school != "" && school != null) {
                    setCookie("SelectedSchool", school, 365);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't really understand how to implement it, I'm really bad at js.

Comment: Copy this whole section in your html page, then call these three function as required.

Comment: I've copied it, how do I call the functions properly?

Comment: Are you called the function or not ?

Comment: No, I haven't done anything besides copying the code. And I'm planning on adding more schools in the future, is that possible with this script?

Comment: These are generic function, you can add school as many you want. You have to call setCookie() function on button onclick event. and onload of body, call getCookie() to get already selected school from the user

Comment: To Implement these function you required little bit Javascript, so spend half hour on this JavaScript Tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp  or http://www.2ality.com/2013/06/basic-javascript.html, then try to implement